# Application crashed in enumerateObjectsUsingBlock

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks

My application crashed at following codes:

> `NSMutableArray* array = [dict objectForKey:key];`
>   `if (array)`
>   `{`
>        `__block BOOL find = NO;`
>        `[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {`
>        `NSString* word = (NSString*)obj;`
>        `if ([word isEqualToString:@"jerry"]) {`
>             `*stop = YES;`
>             `find = YES;`
>        `}`
>   `}];`

And the crash information is:

> `1 CoreFoundation 0x2ecd30f2 __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation) + 90`
>   `2 CoreFoundation 0x2ecd3024 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] (in CoreFoundation) + 232`

I can't figure it out, anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: just remove pointer from BOOL *stop

Comment: sorry I wrote something wrong, it should be [word isEqualToString:@"jerry"], but it's not the reason.

Comment: Is there any exception message? - Is there more code in the block that you did not show?

Comment: @TapanNathvani why? this function does have a  "BOOL *stop"

Comment: are you sure that what you are getting from dic is an array?

Comment: Would be it possible that it have asynchronous modifications made on this array, while you enumerate it ?

Comment: @MartinR There's no more codes in the block except that i have a cast, which is similar to  'NSString* word = (NSString*)obj;'.   Is above-mentioned code has any problem?

Comment: @Emmanuel I do not modify this array inside the block.

Comment: @Joshua yes, it's an array absolutely.

Comment: No modifications of the array in another thread ? not inside the block.

Comment: hey, i used your code.. instead of your array, i just used my sample array and its working for me...so there may be something wrong in your array.

Comment: @Emmanuel every time i get the  `array` from `dict`, and i don't find modifications of `array` in other threads.

Comment: clean and restart your xcode. tried your code with a valid array and its working on my end. even try modifying it in a different thread still not giving me the error you mentioned

Comment: @MartinR with above-mentioned crash information, what you think probably causes this problem?

Comment: @Joshua it crashes sometimes, not always.

Comment: @JerryChu: It seems impossible to answer your question with the currently provided information. Are you sure that there is no other exception message? Did you try to set a "Breakpoint on all Objective-C Exceptions"? What happens if you just `NSLog(@"%@", obj)` in the block and nothing else?

Answer (score 2):

try to use:

```
[word isEqualToString:@"jerry"]
```

Comment: sorry I wrote something wrong, it should be [word isEqualToString:@"jerry"], but it's not the reason

Comment: And comparing strings with "==" would not cause a crash or exception.

Comment: Exactly. So I think it's not the reason it crashes.

Comment: It's amazing how this question had some many upvotes, when it doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
     NSString* word = (NSString*)obj;
     if ([word isEqualToString:@"jerry"]) {
          stop = YES;
          find = YES;
     }
```

You are comparing strings in the wrong way.

Comment: This is wrong. `BOOL *stop` is the correct argument for the enumeration block. - And comparing strings with "==" would not cause an crash.

Comment: - (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block NS_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSMutableArray* array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dict objectForKey:key]];
if (array)
{
     __block BOOL find = NO;
     [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
     NSString* word = (NSString*)obj;
     if ([word isEqualToString:@"jerry"]) {
          *stop = YES;
          find = YES;
     }
}];
```

Comment: This is wrong. `BOOL *stop` is the correct argument for the enumeration block. - And comparing strings with "==" would not cause an crash.

Answer (score 0):

My money is on your array turning out to not actually be an array.  When you create and set your array from the object in dict, check to see that [dict objectForKey:key] is actually an array.

```
NSMutableArray* array = [dict objectForKey:key];
NSLog(@"class of array:  %@", [[dict objectForKey:key] class]);
```

Comment: I don't think so. Look at the crash messages: `enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:` is sent to an `__NSArrayM` object, i.e. a mutable dictionary.

Comment: @MartinR You're right, I might have to throw in the towel for today and go to sleep, it's 5:00am where I am, haven't gone to bed yet and I'm starting to get blurry vision :)  I still think the problem lies somewhere in the array.  enum code looks fine, and I can't seem to replicate a crash with this code unless I set [dict objectForKey:key] to something other than an array